# tftp vs tftp-hpa

Tags: ubuntu, tftp

I'm trying to set up a tftp server on my notebook (using Ubuntu 10.4). I've come across many tutorials, however some refer to tftp-hpa and others to tftp. I've noticed that both exist on the repositories, and after reading a while, I understand that hpa is an enhanced version.

Should I prefer one over the other for some strong reason?  Right now I'll settle with the one that works (can't get a file so far).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Well, the `tftpd-hpa` description says:

> `tftp-hpa` is an enhanced version of the BSD TFTP client and server. It possesses a number of bugfixes and enhancements over the original.

So you should certainly choose the `-hpa` version, unless you are *required* to use the BSD version for some reason (which doesn't seem your case).
BTW, you can also check the `atftpd` package.